# how to execute a bash script on remote server while I am connecting to it

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, server-administration

I am already connected to a remote server using ssh with running the following command

```
ssh user@ip
```

and connected to that server and I am in that server terminal now.

I want to execute a script exist on my loca machine on the remote server while I am connecting to it.

I know that there is another way to do that by doing something like this

```
ssh serverA "bash -s" -- < ./ex.bash
```

but my case is different, I want to execute the script after connecting to the server

how can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps the most convenient way to copy files between two hosts is to use `rsync`. In your case, use this to copy `ex. bash` to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Without a shared volume, like via NFS, you can't do it. If it's a simple script then you can `scp /some/ex.bash remote:/tmp/ex.bash` and then when you ssh to `remote` you can run `/tmp/ex.bash`.

Setting up NFS is more involved than an SO answer. See something like: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-20-04